# Operator issue ANTLR

Tags: parsing, operators, expression, antlr, grammar

It seems like this is my 1000th question today :) I'm so close to finishing my grammar, I just have an issue if a prefix and infix operator share the same symbol. I'm parsing a markup language known as MathML...

```
grammar MathMLOperators;

options 
{
  output = AST;
  backtrack = true;
  memoize = true;
}

tokens
{
  DOCUMENT; // The root of the parsed document.
  GROUP;

  OP; // any operator
  PREFIX_OP; // a prefix operator.
  INFIX_OP; // an infix operator.
  POSTFIX_OP; // a postfix operator.
  NON_INFIX_OP; // a non-infix operator
}

// Start rule.
public document :  math+ -> ^(DOCUMENT math+);

inFixTag : TAG_START_OPEN MO  TAG_CLOSE ('-' | '+' | '=') TAG_END_OPEN MO TAG_CLOSE -> ^(INFIX_OP);

preFixTag : TAG_START_OPEN MO TAG_CLOSE ('+' | '-') TAG_END_OPEN MO TAG_CLOSE -> ^(PREFIX_OP);

// Use semantic predicate to only allow postfix expressions when at the end of an mrow.
postFixTag : TAG_START_OPEN MO TAG_CLOSE ('!' | '^') TAG_END_OPEN MO {input.LT(1).getType() == TAG_CLOSE && input.LT(2).getType() == TAG_END_OPEN && input.LT(3).getType() == MROW && input.LT(4).getType() == TAG_CLOSE}? TAG_CLOSE -> ^(POSTFIX_OP);

nonInfixTag : TAG_START_OPEN MO TAG_CLOSE ('!' | '^') TAG_END_OPEN MO TAG_CLOSE {$expressionList::count++;} -> ^(OP);

opTag: TAG_START_OPEN MO TAG_CLOSE  ('-' | '+' | '^' |'=')  TAG_END_OPEN MO TAG_CLOSE -> ^(NON_INFIX_OP);

//Expressions

infixExpression:  grouping (inFixTag^ grouping)*;
grouping : nestedExpression+ -> ^(GROUP nestedExpression+);

prefixExpression : /* check that it's the first in the mrow*/ {$expressionList::count == 0}? (preFixTag^ (primaryExpression | nonInfixTag)) {$expressionList::count++;};

postfixExpression : (primaryExpression | prefixExpression| nonInfixTag) (postFixTag^)? ;

expressionList scope {int count} @init{$expressionList::count = 0;} :  (infixExpression | opTag)+;

nestedExpression :  postfixExpression;

primaryExpression : mrow | mn;

math : TAG_START_OPEN root=MATH TAG_CLOSE expressionList TAG_END_OPEN MATH TAG_CLOSE -> ^($root expressionList);

mrow : TAG_START_OPEN root=MROW TAG_CLOSE expressionList? TAG_END_OPEN MROW TAG_CLOSE -> ^($root expressionList?);

mn: TAG_START_OPEN root=MN TAG_CLOSE INT TAG_END_OPEN MN TAG_CLOSE -> ^($root INT);

MATH : 'math'; // root tag
MROW : 'mrow'; // row
MO   : 'mo'; // operator
MN   : 'mn'; // number

TAG_START_OPEN : '<';
TAG_END_OPEN : '</' ;
TAG_CLOSE : '>';
TAG_EMPTY_CLOSE : '/>';

INT :   '0'..'9'+;

WS  :  (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

This will work fine...

```
<math>
<mrow>
<mo>-</mo>
<mn>7</mn>
<mo>=</mo>
<mn>8</mn>
</mrow>
</math>
```

But this will fail...

```
<math>
<mrow>
<mo>-</mo>
<mn>7</mn>
<mo>-</mo>
<mn>8</mn>
</mrow>
</math>
```

The first '-' should be 'prefix' and the second should be 'infix'. From the debugger it seems that the rule `grouping` is looping and not returning to the parent rule `infixExpression`, even when it can't match.

I'm sure I have an EBNF operator wrong somewhere, but I'm puzzled as to which one. I've tried to follow a standard expression nesting pattern found in languages like C, but this is an unusual language to parse.

Comment: You may want to push more of the XML bits down into the lexer so that you can parse your input as courser-grained tokens, like `START_MATH START_ROW OP NUM OP NUM END_ROW END_MATH`. I assume that your grammar will be more complex than this in the future and that tokenizing will get harder, but if it's difficult to tell what's going on at this stage, it probably won't get easier.

Comment: At the moment, the lexing is pretty much working fine. The reason I can't make tokens like you suggest is that tags can also contain attributes, and so I need to place a subrule between the tags. My problem is my nested structure for different operator precedences.

How could I do achieve that a prefixExpression can only appear at the start of an expressionList. I think my way of using a scope and updating/checking the variable is the problem.

Comment: I cleaned up just the lexer rules to make the parser rules readable (didn't touch `count` or predicates that I can see) and the error is gone: the ASTs are identical except for the change in operators. I don't know what else to suggest other than make sure you can read it first because it's going to get messier. Otherwise you're going to be better off walking an XML document.

Comment: I've just cleaned the tokens also, and the error is still there. Would you mind sending me the grammar you modified as you say the error has dissappeared? I know you think my lexer is messer, but it's not the source of the problem. The problem is with using an mrow as a primaryExpression inside an expressionList, but I can't figure out why.

<math>
<mo>-</mo>
<mn>1</mn>
<mo>-</mo>
<mn>2</mn>
</math>

works and this doesn't...

<math>
<mrow>
<mo>-</mo>
<mn>1</mn>
<mo>-</mo>
<mn>2</mn>
</mrow>
</math>

Answer (score 1):

> Would you mind sending me the grammar...

Here's the grammar as it looks after I've cleaned it up.

**Caveat:** I can't explain how the parser in the question behaves (hence my cleaning it up), so I don't know what I unintentionally broke/fixed from the original -- telling me that the AST or the parser is now wrong won't mean anything to me because to me it looked wrong to begin with. ;)

```
grammar MathMLOperators;

options 
{
  output = AST;
  backtrack = true;
  memoize = true;
}

tokens
{
  DOCUMENT; // The root of the parsed document.
  GROUP;
  OP; // any operator
  PREFIX_OP; // a prefix operator.
  INFIX_OP; // an infix operator.
  POSTFIX_OP; // a postfix operator.
  NON_INFIX_OP; // a non-infix operator
}

// Start rule.
public document :  math+ EOF -> ^(DOCUMENT math+);

inFixTag        : (op=MINUS | op=PLUS | op=EQ)  -> INFIX_OP[$op.text];
preFixTag       : (op=MINUS | op=PLUS)          -> PREFIX_OP[$op.text]; 

// Use semantic predicate to only allow postfix expressions when at the end of an mrow.
postFixTag      : (op=BANG | op=CARET) {input.LA(1) == CMROW}?      -> POSTFIX_OP[$op.text];
nonInfixTag     : (op=BANG | op=CARET) {$expressionList::count++;}  -> NON_INFIX_OP[$op.text];
opTag           : (op=MINUS | op=PLUS | op=CARET | op=EQ)           -> OP[$op.text];

//Expressions

infixExpression     : grouping (inFixTag^ grouping)*;
grouping            : nestedExpression+     -> ^(GROUP nestedExpression+);

prefixExpression    : /* check that it's the first in the mrow*/ 
                    {$expressionList::count == 0}? 
                        (preFixTag^ (primaryExpression | nonInfixTag)) 
                        {$expressionList::count++;}
                    ;

postfixExpression   : (primaryExpression | prefixExpression| nonInfixTag) (postFixTag^)? ;

expressionList scope {int count} @init{$expressionList::count = 0;} :  (infixExpression | opTag)+;

nestedExpression    :  postfixExpression;

primaryExpression   : mrow | NUM;

math    : MATH expressionList CMATH -> ^(MATH expressionList);

mrow    : MROW expressionList? CMROW -> ^(MROW expressionList?);

///////   LEXER   ///////

MATH    : TAG_START_OPEN WS* 'math' WS* TAG_CLOSE; // root tag
CMATH   : TAG_END_OPEN WS* 'math' WS* TAG_CLOSE;

MROW    : TAG_START_OPEN WS* 'mrow' WS* TAG_CLOSE; // row
CMROW   : TAG_END_OPEN WS* 'mrow' WS* TAG_CLOSE;

fragment OMO    : TAG_START_OPEN WS* 'mo' WS* TAG_CLOSE; // operator
fragment CMO    : TAG_END_OPEN WS* 'mo' WS* TAG_CLOSE; 

MINUS   : OMO '-' CMO {setText("-");};
PLUS    : OMO '+' CMO {setText("+");};
EQ      : OMO '=' CMO {setText("=");};
BANG    : OMO '!' CMO {setText("!");};
CARET   : OMO '^' CMO {setText("^");};


NUM     : TAG_START_OPEN WS* 'mn' WS* TAG_CLOSE 
            INT 
          TAG_END_OPEN WS* 'mn' WS* TAG_CLOSE 
          {setText($INT.text);}
        ;

fragment TAG_START_OPEN : '<';
fragment TAG_END_OPEN   : '</' ;
fragment TAG_CLOSE      : '>';
fragment TAG_EMPTY_CLOSE: '/>';

INT     :   '0'..'9'+;

WS      :  (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

#### Test Case 1 : Infix '=' with MROW

Input:

```
    <math>
    <mrow>
    <mo>-</mo>
    <mn>7</mn>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mn>8</mn>
    </mrow>
    </math>
```

Output:

[image: infix = with mrow]

#### Test Case 2: Infix '-' with MROW

Input:

```
    <math>
    <mrow>
    <mo>-</mo>
    <mn>7</mn>
    <mo>-</mo>
    <mn>8</mn>
    </mrow>
    </math>
```

Output:

[image: infix - with mrow]

#### Test Case 3: Infix '-' without MROW

Input:

```
    <math>
    <mo>-</mo>
    <mn>7</mn>
    <mo>-</mo>
    <mn>8</mn>
    </math>
```

Output:

[image: infix - without mrow]

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to reproduce your tests in ANTLRWorks.

Comment: @DavidJamesBall I originally ran these with custom code but I'm able to reproduce the results for test case #2 in ANTLRWorks v1.4.3 & v1.5rc1 (I haven't tried the other cases -- I assume they'd work if #2 did).  What version are you running and what are you seeing/not seeing?

Comment: oh sorry, just me being stupid. I've been use to seeing PREFIX_OP and POSTFIX_OP instead of the actual operator. It seems to work in order now. Fingers crossed. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @DavidJamesBall Gotcha. One reason I use my own test code is to dump out both the token type and its text into the graph. I'm glad I could help, although I still don't know what I did. :P

Comment: Yeah, I'm not 100% sure why it should now work after the tokens have been simplified, surely the parser should be matching the same stuff, even if a little verbose.